# Xamarin Android App won't build after adding a PNG resource

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to build a freshly created Xamarin.Forms app for the Android platform. I'm getting all sorts of errors (73 at the moment) about missing @drawable files.

The errors go away if I remove a particular PNG file from my Resources/drawable folder. It's an image I use for a page background. Currently it's only 515KB and is 500x750 in size. The resource has a build action of AndroidResource, just like another PNG file I have included (smaller file, but it works fine).

If I remove this PNG, my app will build and deploy just fine in the debugger. If I put the PNG back in, even if I remove the reference to it from my code, it fails... but not on THIS graphic, but on a bunch of others:

[image: Errors]

I've renamed my file a few times to make sure I'm in accordance with Android naming conventions...

My graphic is simple "pagebg.png"

[image: pagebg.png]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had this problem before and had figured out the problem. This error arises when you change just the extension to .PNG , rather you should open file in paint or something and properly save it as a .PNG file. This solution will surely resolve the issue. Let me know if it doesn't

**Happy Coding**

Comment: That might have been the case. I received the PNG from my designer, who may have simply renamed it or something. What did work for me was making a fresh PNG file, so maybe that's exactly what happened... makes sense.

Comment: yes, just changing the extension name doesn't make it a png file, so that may fool the user but not the compiler :D

Answer (score 0):

Well... I recreated my PNG file and added it back in... something about the file's contents was causing this. Does Android actually look inside the binary files for something when building the app?